# Microsoft Edge prompts for authentication when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, iis, microsoft-edge

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine in a domain environment where I am not a local admin on the development PC.  When I press F5 to start debugging my MVC project with Microsoft Edge I get a Windows Security prompt asking for credentials.  I enter my domain account credentials (the one I am already to logged into the PC with) and my page displays.

As I understand it, IIS Express uses my local credentials anyway so why am I being prompted for username and password every time I press F5?  It's very frustrating and previously I gave up and decided to use Internet Explorer instead but now that I have a new PC and still have this issue I'm wondering if there could be some checkbox that I can tick somewhere before I go insane.

Comment: No one?  Nice browser support MS, doesn't even work out of the box with your own dev tools.  Come on guys...

Comment: I guess it does work for most people.  But it's still driving me crazy.  I'm on my third PC build now with a new version of Visual Studio.  I like Edge but I still can't use it for development.

Answer (score 1):

Press “Windows+X” and go to “control panel”.
Click on “credential manager” and go to “web credentials” and "window credentials"
Then remove the password and read the credentials.
** Remove window credentials corresponding to IP showing on EDGE:-

Fore more detail:-
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/edge-message-server-asking-for-username-and/32e06d1f-7462-4b1a-8eef-33e5581542b5